# How do I find out what happened on this flight?

Tags: incidents, online-tracking

On 2017-01-03 [DAL58](http://de.flightaware.com/live/flight/DAL58/history/20170104/0044Z/KBOS/EGLL) from Boston to London apparently returned to New York after 90 minutes of flight.

This seems quite irregular to me, and I had expected to find details about this published somewhere. I tried Google, and I searched at avherald.com for the date and also for B763, but didn't find anything.

Was this not sufficiently irregular to warrant some kind of public information about what happened on this flight? Or if such information is published, where could I find it? Or is such information only available to certain people?

Comment: Call the airline and ask? Mind you, if you have no real reason for asking, they have no real reason for answering.

Comment: @J.Hougaard good point, indeed I don't have a good reason to ask - I'm just curious and thought there were public sources of information for this.

Comment: Not really. Just like there aren't public sources with information about car accidents, delayed trains, cancelled ferries and so on.

Comment: Can't find anything specific on that flight, but the drop in cruise altitude might indicate engine issues (but it could also just be that that's where ATC needed them for flying the opposite direction.)

Comment: Looking around on liveatc.net, I did see a couple of trans-Altantic flights that diverted to Shannon, Ireland (one for health emergency, one for unruly passenger) and a United flight from Sydney to SFO that diverted to Auckland due to an unruly passenger on that day, but I didn't see the Delta flight.

Comment: @reirab good point about liveatc.net, that's an interesting separate source.

Comment: If it was something critical like an engine failure, they would have diverted to an airport that was much closer. What likely happened was some sort of malfunction that meant they couldn't fly on to London but was not critical. They would have diverted to a place that would be most convenient for the passengers to get them on other flights, which they assessed to be JFK. This type of decision making is quite common and safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues in flight are more common than we think: engine shutting down in flight, fumes in cabin, ... Aircraft are huge pieces of engineering with many parts and sensors that can fail. Aircraft have many redundancies which most of the time allows for a safe landing.

I tried to look on the [avherald](http://avherald.com/), a reliable and extensive source of aircraft reports, incidents and accidents, mainly fed by its owner and its users but the flight does not appear there. However you can appreciate the number of incidents occurring every day and this is a small part of them.

Comment: This is all good points, don't forget medical emergencies as well.